# Progress bar change colour

Tags: vb.net, progress-bar

im trying to change the colour of the progress bar for a custom control. ive tryed quite a few methords like using the sendingmessage function below:

> ```
> <DllImport("User32.Dll")> _
> Public Shared Function SendMessage(hwnd As Integer, wMsg As Integer, wParam As Integer, lParam As Integer) As Integer
> End Function
> ```

```
Public Const PBM_SETBKCOLOR As Integer = &H2001
Public Const PBM_SETBARCOLOR As Integer = &H409

Public Sub SetProgressBackColor(c As Color)

    Dim a As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(c.R.ToString())
    Dim b As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(c.G.ToString())
    Dim d As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(c.B.ToString())
    Dim tot As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.FromArgb(a, b, d)).ToString())
    Dim j As Integer = Me.PercentFull.Handle.ToInt32()
    SendMessage(j, PBM_SETBKCOLOR, 0, tot)
End Sub

Public Sub SetProgressForeColor(c As Color)

    Dim a As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(c.R.ToString())
    Dim b As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(c.G.ToString())
    Dim d As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(c.B.ToString())
    Dim tot As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.FromArgb(a, b, d)).ToString())
    Dim j As Integer = Me.PercentFull.Handle.ToInt32()
    SendMessage(j, PBM_SETBARCOLOR, 0, tot)
End Sub
```

but this didnt work for me i couldent see any change.

what would be the best way for me to change the forecolor for this control? i cannot use PercentFull.ForeColor as i will have xp styles enabled.

Thanks

Comment: no but it is for a custom control so i dont have the option to disable the xp styles. Also this control could be used for xp machines. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The `BackColor` just sends this messages.
As the documentation states,

> When visual styles are enabled, this message has no effect.

You cannot do this.

Comment: @user3026015: The question stated that he wants visual styles enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Over on CodeProject, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9635/A-Smooth-ProgressBar-for-everyone-Part-Duex, Stumpy has created a SmoothProgressBar that allows you to create progressbars with changeable colors.  Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for you help but i decided to use The follow:

> SendMessage(PercentFull.Handle, &H400 + 16, &H2, 0) 'Error; Red
>   SendMessage(PercentFull.Handle, &H400 + 16, &H3, 0) 'Pause; Yellow
>   SendMessage(PercentFull.Handle, &H400 + 16, &H1, 0) 'Pause;green